# Neo4j with Jruby project rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, constants, neo4j

I am trying use neo4j with Ruby on rails on Mac OSX.
I have installed jruby and neo4j with brew.
I followed this guide:
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_With_Ruby
and this:
https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j
Firstly, my server Neo4j started and I was able to create a node and a relation.

I have created a new gemset with RVM (ree install jruby@neo4j).
Secondly, the test's first guide was successful.

So, I have created a new project with command's second guide.
The project was created and the bundle was successful.
But when I went to start the server (`rails s`) it gave me:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j::Rails::Application
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2590
          Neo4j at /Users/guillaumelegendre/dev/boosket/neo4j/config/application.rb:19
         (root) at /Users/guillaumelegendre/dev/boosket/neo4j/config/application.rb:18
        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
         (root) at /Users/guillaumelegendre/dev/boosket/neo4j/config/application.rb:52
            tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1804
         (root) at /Users/guillaumelegendre/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.3@neo4j/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49
        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
         (root) at script/rails:6
```

I searched on Google, but I did't find anybody with the same error.

And this was my application.rb but this is the application.rb belonging to the second script's guide:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'active_resource/railtie'
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
require 'will_paginate/railtie'
require 'neo4j'


if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Neo4j
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable Neo4j generators, e.g:  rails generate model Admin --parent User
    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm             :neo4j
      g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => false
    end

    # Configure where the neo4j database should exist
    config.neo4j.storage_path = "#{config.root}/db/neo4j-#{Rails.env}"


    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, what version of rails, jruby and neo4j do you use ?
It should work out of the box:

```
gem install rails
rails new myapp -m http://andreasronge.github.com/rails3.rb
cd myapp
bundle
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
rails s
open a webbrowser: http://localhost:3000/users
```

How can I reproduce this problem ?

Comment: I use Jruby 1.6.3
neo4j community-1.5
rails 3.1.3

If i try:
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
Server answer me the same error.

I have seen no error the last time I do install. But if you don't see reason I try to reinstall all clean. And I will deliver you the result.

I appreciate your interest.

Comment: You should not install neo4j ! It's an embedded database and the neo4j gem includes everything. Which version of the gem do you use ? You should also use latest jruby 1.6.5 what does: ruby -v tell you (just to make sure you really are on jruby)

Comment: I'm on jruby 1.6.3 apparently I need to config rvm to use 1.6.5 (who are ruby 1.9 if I correctly understood contrary to 1.6.3 who are ruby 1.8.7). I don't know if it's important.

Comment: Sry. I use the gem neo4j 1.3.1

Comment: The version jruby 1.6.5 was the reason. Thx for all.